# Ubuntu 18.04 New Netplan / IP Configuration (pointopoint?) (Need Example)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ifconfig, ipconfig, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Root-Server with Proxmox installed. Until now, i always had Ubuntu 17. Now i upgraded a VM to Ubuntu 18 and i need a example for the new netplan Configuration.

This was my old interfaces file:

auto ens18
iface ens18 inet static
  address 195.201.52.XXX
  netmask 255.255.255.255
  pointopoint 195.201.8.YYY
  gateway 195.201.8.YYY
  dns-nameservers 213.133.98.98 213.133.99.99 213.133.100.100 8.8.8.8

Because i couldn't find the option pointopoint with the new netplan i'm struggeling to activate this VM. I know i could simply install ifupdown again. But if there is a possibillity i would like to keep the new netplan. Could anyone help me out with this ?

Thanks in advance,
Roger

Comment: Try superuser or Linux & Unix stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

You could (with a ton of work) use interfaces but I highly suggest that you use Netplan. In order for this to work you have to edit
`/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file.

It would look like this with your requirements:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
      ens18:
              addresses: [195.201.52.XXX/32]
              gateway4: 195.201.8.YYY
              dhcp4: false
              nameservers:
                      addresses: [213.133.98.98,213.133.99.99,213.133.100.100,8.8.8.8]
```

I couldn't find a alternative for P2P either, so you have to search more on your own.